# Hook Singleton - implementation using module scoped aggregate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was wondering if there is a valid solution for a React hook that would act in a singleton manner without taking advantage of Context or other 3rd party libraries. I figured the following implementation where singleton hooks are module scoped using `singletonInstances`. The implementation seems to be working fine and it's easy to use, but I'm worried that it is not in "compliance" with React's framework and that it will fail on me in the future. Can a seasoned React developers could provide some feedback in regards to the following solution?

```
import { useMemo } from "react";

type HookFunction<T, P extends any[]> = (...args: P) => T;

type SingletonInstances = Record<string, unknown>;

const singletonInstances: SingletonInstances = {};

export function useSingleton<T, P extends any[]>(
  hookFn: HookFunction<T, P>,
  ...args: P
) {
  const hookName = hookFn.name;

  return useMemo(() => {
    if (!singletonInstances[hookName]) {
      singletonInstances[hookName] = hookFn(...args);
    }
    return singletonInstances[hookName] as T;
  }, [...args]);
}
```

Usage:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useSingleton } from "./useSingleton";

function useSomeHook() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  // hook's logic...
  
   return [count, setCount];
}

export default function useSome() {
  return useSingleton(useSomeHook);
}
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more why? Curious to learn what is the use case when you think this going to be helpful and why no Context?

Comment: Just for the code to be more concise and simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately presented approach started to crash on me after a while. Changing the implementation to utilize React's contexts fixed the issue, making this approach not a suitable candidate for usage within React's framework.